# Constructing a 95% Confidence Interval (using output from r-studio)

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

> Consider a random sample $X_1,X_2,..,X_n$ from a variable with density function
>   $$f_X(x)=2\lambda\pi xe^{-\lambda\pi x^2} \ \ \ \ \ \ \  x>0$$
>   A useful estimator of $\lambda$ is $$\hat{\lambda}=\frac{n}{\pi\sum_{i=1}^{n} X^2_1}$$
>   David was studying the spatial distribution of a native Acacia species.
>   At one site, 12 points were randomly selected, and at each point, he measured (in metres) the distance to the nearest Acacia plant. The resulting
>   measurements are given below.
>   $$ 0.015 \ \ \ 0.09 \ \ \  0.046\ \ \ 0.24 \ \ \ 0.17 \ \ \  0.31$$
>   $$0.29 \ \ \ 0.22 \ \ \  0.21 \ \ \ 0.26 \ \ \ 0.34 \ \ \ 0.79$$
>   Assume that $f(x)$ is a good model for the density function of point to
>   nearest neighbour distance where $λ$ is the density of the Acacia plants
>   (in plants per square metre).
>   Compute a 95% confidence interval for $λ$ from the above data. You may
>   use the following result

```
> qgamma(c(0.025,0.05,0.95,0.975),6,6)
[1] 0.3669824 0.4355025 1.7521725 1.9447220
> qgamma(c(0.025,0.05,0.95,0.975),12,12)
[1] 0.5167146 0.5770177 1.5172929 1.6401699
```

The above output is from R.

To compute a 95% confidence interval given a sample of measurements, I thought the interval would take the form
$$\Big(\overline{X}-t_{n-1,0.975}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},\overline{X}+t_{n-1,0.975}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\Big)$$
where $S$ is the sample variance, which I calculated to be $0.199$ and $\overline{X}$ is the standard mean which I calculated to be $0.248$. Now for $t_{n-1,0.975}$, I could use a t-value table, but this was not given in the exam. We are required to use the output from R.

Given the information in the question, how should I construct my confidence interval?

Comment: $\bar{X} \pm t_{n-1, 1-\alpha/2}\dfrac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$ does not apply outside of the $t$-distribution.

Comment: That's what I was worried of. Do you have any hints on how best to find the confidence interval?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841618/95-confidence-interval-for-lambda Already answer how to construct an exact CI for this situation, you just need to apply the result. If need further explanation, please ask.

Comment: I have included an answer to the link in your comment. Is it correct? I will need it to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

When the population distribution is normal (or approximately normal), 95% confidence intervals of the type $\hat \mu \pm 1.96\text{SD}(\hat \mu)/\sqrt{n}$
are used. When it is necessary to estimate $\text{SD}(\hat \mu)$ from the sample, then 1.96 is replaced by a number $t_c$ that cuts 2.5% of the probability from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with the relevant degrees of freedom.

However, when dealing with parameter estimates that have asymmetrical distributions, such as chi-squared or gamma, the type of CI that is symmetrical about $\hat \mu$ is not usually feasible.

@BGM's suggested link deals with another kind of CI that does often work
in such situations. And the method to get the specific CI you seek is indeed shown there.
Perhaps a second example of that kind of CI will be helpful:

If you have $n$ observations from a normal population with unknown variance $\sigma^2,$ here is how to get a CI for $\sigma$ using the sample variance $S^2.$
One can show that $Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$
Then you can find values $L$ and $U$ that cut 2.5% of the area from the lower and upper tails (respectively) of $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-1)$ so that
$$0.95 = P(L < Q < U) = P\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U} < \sigma^2 < \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right).$$
This imples that a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form 
$$\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U},\; \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right).$$

*Notes:* (1) The point estimate $S^2$ of $\sigma^2$ will lie within this CI, but not typically at the *center* of the interval. (2) By adjusting the amounts of probability (adding to 5%) that are put into each tail, you can usually get a CI that is a bit
shorter. (3) The interval shown above with 2.5% in each tail is called 'probability-symmetric'. (4) To get a 95% CI for the population standard deviation $\sigma$ take square roots of the endpoints of the 95% CI for $\sigma^2.$ (5) You can get the values $L$ and $U$ from printed tables of chi-squared distributions or by using statistical software such as R.